# Why does getServerSideProps doesn't pass the right value to the component props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from 4 different endpoints and pass them as props with getServerSideProps (Next.js) but despite the fact that the "courses" variable that is being returned from getServerSideProps DOES contain the required courses, the parameter { courses } received by the component turns out to be an empty array ([])

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'
import Courses from '../../components/career/Courses'
import JobExperiences from '../../components/career/JobExperiences'
import University from '../../components/career/University'
import Layout from '../../components/ui/Layout'
import SectionDescription from '../../components/ui/SectionDescription'
import { Course } from '../../data/interfaces/career/Course'
import { useTranslation } from '../../hooks/useTranslation'

interface CareerProps {
    courses: Course[]
}

const Career = ({ courses }: CareerProps) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

return (
    <Layout title="Career">
        <section className="p-5 sm:p-8 md:p-16 lg:p-32">
            <header>
                <SectionDescription title={t.career.title} description={t.career.description} />
            </header>
            <JobExperiences />
            <University />
            <Courses courses={courses} />
        </section>
    </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {

const courses: Course[] = []

const courseIDs = [
    "1362070",
    "3096364",
    "947098",
    "1879018",
]

courseIDs.forEach(async courseID => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/${courseID}/`);
    courses.push(data)
})

return {
    props: { courses: courses },
}
}

export default Career
```

Comment: `forEach` will not wait for the promises to be resolved even though you are using async await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the API calls with the following because `forEach` cannot handle the `async-await` calls as you expect:

```js
await Promise.all(
    courseIDs.map(async (courseID) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/${courseID}/`);
        courses.push(data);
    })
);
```